# ng-Ckeditor, angularjs: Sometimes, ckeditor could not load data to display in html

Tags: angularjs, ng-ckeditor

I'm using ng-ckeditor http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-ckeditor for angularjs app.

My-code
.html

```
<textarea ng-model="target.Content" ckeditor></textarea>
```

.js

```
getData().then(response){
$scope.target.Content = response;
})
```

I have a problem is:
Sometimes, CkEditor in Html display nothing. I don't understand why
Please, help me!.

Comment: getData().then(function(response){$scope.target.Content = response;}) try this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mention. @Nikita